# Upload pcb project on pcb service - Error

Tags: pcb, altium, fritzing

I have found a pcb service online: aisler.net.
After uploaded the project on the site appears the board prew with a error message:

```
"The board does not contain outer bounds. It can't be manufactured like this. The outer bounds should be on the dimensions (EAGLE) or Edge.Cuts (KiCad) layer.".
```

What does it mean?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a layer to your board that has the outline of the board. This will define the shear lines, router bit paths and V-groove lines in your board. In a simple board it is probably just a square or rectangle, on a more complex board it may have text on it to indicate V-groove cuts, routed slots between mouse bites, etc.

Output and include the Gerber file for that layer and send it to the PCB house.

You may import the outline in .DXF format from a CAD package, especially in more complex situations where the board contours are not a simple rectangle or rectangle with rounded corners.

Personally, I usually use the Mechanical 5 layer in Altium, but it's arbitrary.

Here is a typical outline layer as displayed in Camtastic:

[image]

The width of the lines is not too important, the cuts will be made to the center of the lines, so something like 0.2mm that is wide enough to be easily seen, yet not too crude, works well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using KiCAD, make sure you have selected Edge.Cuts layer in the Gerber files output.

[image]

This will determine PCB edges.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory the board house can't find the outer bounds of your pcb. Your design is lacking an outline.

According to the Eagle page with layer information.

> Layer 20: Dimension
>   The Dimension layer has several purposes, the first of which is to specify the outline of your board. Secondarily, you can also use this layer in your design rules to keep copper pours away from the edge of your PCB.
>   Some fab houses like OSH Park will use this Dimension layer to generate a board outline Gerber. This will serve as the exact shape of your PCB when they cut it into a fabrication panel.

[image: Outline eagle]

I don't know what program you are using, but lookup how to define the outline of your pcb and provide this to the boardhouse.